# An android application keeps opening new browser tab every time it's launched

Tags: android, android-intent

I created a simple android application that launches a browser upon clicking it. However, the application opens a new tab every time it's launched. Here is the sample code I wrote to start the activity of the browser. I just need my code to avoid opening multiple tabs instead open the tab that is already opened.

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String url = "http://www.google.com";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
```

I know I have to use EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID at some point to avoid the multiple tabs. I just need help how I can use that in order to get the result I need?? 
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is possible to do this as you would have to have access to the internal representation of the browser application, which is most likely forbidden by the android sandbox. If anyone thinks this is incorrect, please correct me, I've tried to do something similar in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Found this while searching for something related.
You can totally do this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
String url = "http://www.google.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));                
intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID,getPackageName() );
startActivity(i);
```

The EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID tells the browser that you want to reuse the same tab.  So if there are no tabs open, it will open another one, but if one of the tabs you opened with this is already open, it will reuse it.

I know this for sure works in Chrome, but it might have different behavior with different browsers.